# R1soft error "MySQL restore already occurring for running instance, cannot continue"

Tags: mysql, database-restore, r1soft

I am using R1soft backup tool on my server(cpanel) and trying to restore the database backup but it gives me the error "restore failed". Attaching logs error here:

Protected Machine: MySQL restore already occurring for running instance, cannot continue 
--> Manager: Failed to start temporary database instance Manager: Agent reported error during requested operation 
--> Manager: Failed to start temporary database instance 
--> Manager: Failed to start temporary database instance 
--> Manager: Agent reported error during requested operation

If anyone has any idea then Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cause for the issue:

When initiating a DB restoration, the CDP Server will transfer MySQL data to the Agent, that will write the data into the cdp-agent's tmp directory (/var/lib/r1soft/tmp). The CDP Agent will also create a temporary instance of MySQL to conduct the restore too. This is where the problem starts occurring. The agent is unable to start the temporary instance. Common causes for this failure are security mechanisms such as SELinux and Apparmor.

You can have this fixed with the resolution below:

If caused by SELinux, put SELinux in permissive mode while doing the restore. If running Apparmor, run "service apparmor teardown", simply running 'aa-complain' for mysqld and "service apparmor stop" will not resolve the issue. Once a tmp MySQL instance is created, the Connector/J will connect to both instances and migrate the InnoDB database from the tmp instance to the primary instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and found that when it failed, it left the process running on my server. I SSH'd in and did a ps axfw | grep r1soft and identified the subprocesses responsible and killed them.

Comment: I should note, do not kill the cdp main process (agent_config)